# Python import from sibling directories

Tags: python, python-import

**Disclaimer:** after searching through tons of very similar feeds that in the end all turn out to solve a slightly different problem I guess I have to open a new question (although I am sure there exists an answer somewhere --> so point that out if you know it ;)

**The problem:** I am using Python 2, am building a project with this tree:

```
project
├── __init__.py
├── foo  
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── bar   
│       └── __init__.py
├── notebooks   
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── skript.py
└── test
    └── __init__.py
    └── foo   
        └── __init__.py
        └── bar   
            └── __init__.py
            └── file.py
```

Now I want to load test.foo.bar from within `project/notebooks/skript.py`. Therefore, I do in that skript

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

If I then run

```
import test.foo.bar  # or: import test.foo
```

python tells me

```
ImportError: No module named foo.bar
```

(or `ImportError: No module named foo` respectively). Funily, `import test` does not throw an error, but if I then do `test.foo` it throws an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'`.

So I wonder, what is going wrong here and how to fix it?

---

**Edit**

Also, I tried adding this to `skript.py`

```
import sys
import os
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(MYDIR,'../test'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(MYDIR,'../test/foo'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(MYDIR,'../test/foo/bar')) #I am not sure this is entirely needed
```

as was pointed out below. Still,

```
import test.foo.bar.file
```

or
    from test.foo.bar import file
just yield

```
ImportError: No module named foo.bar
```

Same for

```
sys.path.append('../test/foo/bar')
import test.foo.bar.file
```

I have still no clue whats going wrong?

Comment: If you append `../` path to the python path you're appending the `project` path, and not the path where the `bar` module is, you should add the `./test/foo/bar` path.

Comment: Your error complains only about ``foo.bar``, not ``test.foo.bar``. Does ``test`` explicitly import ``foo.bar``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing with `sys.path` is rarely a good idea.

Since your plan seems to be to use both `foo` and `test` from `notebooks` (that will probably just contain Jupyter notebooks), the cleanest solution would be to install `foo` and `test` as packages.

Remove the `__init__.py` from your top level directory and `notebooks`, since you will not want to import them. Then add a `setup.py` to your top level directory. Since your tests are specific to `foo`, you should either rename them `foo_test` or move them into `foo` itself.

A minimal `setup.py` would look like this

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='foo',
      version='0.1',
      description='descroption of fo',
      author='you',
      author_email='your@mail',
      packages=['foo','test_foo])
```

Then you can simply `pip install -e .` in your top level directory and it will be installed into your current virtualenv. If you are not using virtualenvs, you should `pip install --user -e .`

Comment: Sweet! That's what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

It should work with

```
from test import foo
```

But you have to add a `__init__.py` to your project directory.

For Python 3 it would be:

```
from .test import foo
```

If you use the dot in front of the folder name, python searches for the file in the same directory as the file you are working on is placed in.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Hmm.. that gives me:
>>> from .test import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` file in the project directory?

Comment: Yes, thats right. Do you have a `__init__.py` file in the project directory?

Comment: I just added one, but it doesn't change a thing :/

Comment: I have now __init__.py files in any directory still no difference. (is there actually a difference between __init__ and init?)

Comment: Not `init.py` but `__init__.py`

Comment: If you want to write a double underline you have to mark it as code with ``. And yes the file has to be `__init__.py`

Comment: Upsi, sorry for the inconvenience... as the bold init signifies, I have put `__init__.py`s in all directories. Still it tells me `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: Can you try to call your script like this: python -m project.notebooks ?

Comment: then it gives me the message `No module named notebooks` (Although I have done `python -m ptoject.notebooks.skript` with `skript.py` a file in `notebooks` that contains the `from .test import foo`)

Comment: Wait you actually did python -m ptoject.notebooks.skript? because you wrote ptoject instead of project.

Comment: nope, that was just a spelling mistake as I did not copy paste

Comment: So you added `__init__.py` to your project directory? Because if you did you should be able to call it like `from test import foo`. Im sorry, you have to use the dot for python 3, not for python 2 I think. Sorry, my fault.

Comment: The error message changed slightly but it still does not work:

Comment: `>>> from test import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name foo
`

Comment: Wait. foo is a directory? and bar is a file? It would be `from test.foo import bar` then.

Comment: Actually both `foo` and `bar` are directories (`foo` is the directory containing all sorts of source code such as many subdirs like `bar` with actual python files inside. And `test/foo/bar` the respective files with various test methods).  Still, if I put a file `file.py` into `test/foo/bar` and then go into notebooks, start python, do `import sys`, `sys.path.append('..')` and then `from test.foo.bar import file` I still get `ImportError: No module named foo.bar`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an IDE? If so add the path to the Python Interpreter inside the project Properties to all the primary packages (foo, test, notebooks). Otherwise try to explicitly add the bar package to the sys path like so

```
import sys
import os
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(MYDIR,'test'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(MYDIR,'test/foo'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(MYDIR,'test/foo/bar')) #I am not sure this is entirely needed
```

Comment: In general I use an IDE but am currently making this working outside the IDE (in particular I wnat to put Jupyter notebooks into the notebooks dir in order to play around with thetest and the source files/methods). 
I tried what you suggested but it still doesn't work (plus you should also import os I suppose ;). 
As you write it, what does that actually do with the test directory?

Comment: Oh right, you are working in `notebooks` not in `tests` I will update my answer. Also yes, I forgot to import `os`.

Comment: Still I get the beautiful `ImportError: No module named foo.bar.file`. But I still wonder what the things you wrote actually do. Isn't MYDIR simply the path to the file, so in this case sth like `.../project/notebooks` such that `sys.path.append(os.path.join(MYDIR,'test'))` will return `.../project/notebooks/test` etc? And this is not even a valid path?

Comment: MYDIR is the path to your current file in execution but I am using it to have a absolute path to the package I am trying to append, try to add `../` before every test

Comment: I see. However, even adding the `../` before every `test` doesn't help. Also I think in principle it should be enough to add the parent directory of notebooks to sys.path. Because then a statement such as `import test.foo.bar` should be clear to the interpreter? Anyways, I will write an edit to the question in order to also note the changes...